# How to make drawable of android app for all density

Tags: icon, images, android

Hello I am Android Developer, working on android application. I require to make all drawables for all density for my android app. Is there any standard ratio I should keep for that and any tool for that. Any idea ?

Comment: what is a 'drawable'?

Answer (score 1):

This is android's guidelines for icons.

36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density

[image]

here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Refer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261344/drawable-sizes-for-different-screen-sizes-in-android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you have Photoshop, it would be good for generating different size drawables.

So giving a example if I like to generate a icon say 48x48dp (Now as per Google **dp** is density independent pixel, **1dp=1pixel on a 160 dpi screen**).

1. So first create a new document in PS of size 48x48 pixels with ppi set to 160. Draw/Paste your image and save it.

   Now generally there are 5 types of screens **low (120 dpi)**, **medium (160 dpi)**, **high (240 dpi)**, **extra high (320 dpi)** and **2*extra high (480 dpi)**.
2. We have already created Icon for 160dpi screen, now change the image PPI (keeping aspect ratio same) to 120/240/320/480 and you'll have drawables for all screens. Put them in respective folders. Cheers !

(You can use other softwares too for changing image size/resolution)

Comment: ppi should be set to 72 for an mdpi drawable, not 160. See here for more info: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/6Eng1FFa2cY

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script that [exports to multiple sizes](http://www.velara3.com/wp/2015/01/22/export-to-multiple-sizes-for-photoshop/). It references Androids docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I've already included the Android recommended values but you  can create your own export icon set.

Answer (score -3):

[you can use this link for all sizes](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)